# How do I securely download configuration files onto iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad

We are writing a corporate app which will run on a small number of in-house iPads.  There will be a need to provide a number of (structurally identical) 'setups' on each iPad, and those setups will contain confidential data. My question is, what's the best way of getting those setups securely onto a device (into the app's private storage).

So far we've considered:

- Download from web.  This is problematical because we'd have to do quite a lot of work to make this secure.
- QR codes.  Render the setup as a QR code.  We can generate and scan QR codes which represent the setups (they are quite small), but it looks like the available QR code APIs are either quite expensive or a little complex.
- iTunes downloads.  This is being looked at but I'm not sure what the security implications are.

Have we missed something simpler?

Edit: Just to clarify, a setup takes the form of a small file. It could be XML or JSON or even plain text: it just needs to encode about ten variable names and their values.

Comment: If you do end up using QR Codes I recommend this library as it simplifies life a lot

Comment: Thanks Armand - was there a link to a specific library in your comment?

Comment: How "confidential" or secure do you want that data to be?  If you make the app available via the web, the only phones / devices you'd be able to run the app on are the ones that are registered & permitted in your Enterprise account.  Or are you worried that malicious people would download the app and look at the raw data?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann - The raw data is very human-readable so I'd be concerned about it getting out with or without the app.  Could encrypt the file of course, but trying to avoid the work involved at both ends of that.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/ sorry forgot to paste the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "iTunes downloads".  If this isn't referring to iTunes File Sharing, then you should look into that.  The user can add files onto the device for particular apps through iTunes.

It's also not clear what you mean by "secure" - this has very different meanings to different people.  Sticking an SSL cert onto a server and providing HTTP auth is simple enough.  What kind of security beyond that are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks @Jim.  It does look like iTunes file sharing is the way to go.

Comment: ...I'll mark as answer in a little while once I'm sure no even more brilliant response comes in.

Comment: ...and if we were going the web route, SSL cert and HTTP auth seems an appropriate level, ta.

Answer (score 0):

If QR codes are acceptable, I suggest you look at [zxing library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/). The code contains an iOS example project that you could base your implementation on.

There are some useful web resources to help with implementation: http://yannickloriot.com/2011/04/how-to-install-zxing-in-xcode-4/